# how to move 2 divs on hover with css

Tags: css, html, hover, parent-child

My current layout goes like this :

I have a parent div named "chapters" which holds the 2 divs inside "listHolder" and "chapterButton"

when i hover on "chapterButton" I want chapterButton and listHolder both to shift 150px to the left, this is to go on a video so when u hover on the chapterButton which is visible on the video player they both shift onto the video player and the chapters (a set of list items) are now visible so you can select your chapter.

at the moment all i can seem to do is move one of the sibling divs at a time. So how can i make both of these shift left at the same time.

im currently using this :

```
.chapterButton:hover + .listHolder{
position:relative;
right:150px;
}
```

this does move .listHolder 150px to the left but how can i change this so on hover .chapterButton and .listHolder move left?

The easiest way would be to move the parent dive left as it contains both these divs, but is this possible if your hovering on the child div ?

Answered by chen asraf below

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPwcX/

i've not put the video in , but at its normal state when the menu is on the right its hidden when its on the left its visible. so i want the arrow to move left with the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.chapterButton:hover, .chapterButton:hover + .listHolder {
    position:relative;
    right:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.chapters:hover > * {
  position:relative;
  right:150px;
}
```